# java.util.Calendar - Year 1947

Tags: java

I found an interesting behavior in WSO2 platform using Calendar to convert String to Date.
WSO2 uses java.util.Calendar as the final result.
I found that if a date from 01.01.1947 - 23.02.1947 is used in code snippet bellow the result always gives us one day before.
I found out that its our Timezone doing this as it is one hour forward. Meaning Calendar decreases result one hour backwards and we get the day before 11PM.

We did already solve the problem by not converting to Date. So that is not the issue.

The question is, why is this happening only for dates 01.01.1947 - 23.02.1947?

Here is an example code snippet that can simulate the issue:

```
    int year = 1947;
    int month = 2;
    int day = 23;
    int timezoneOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.clear();
    calendar.set(1, year);
    calendar.set(2, month - 1);
    calendar.set(5, day);
    calendar.set(15, timezoneOffset);

    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

In my timezone the result of timezoneOffset is 3600000 in case you want to test my timezone (Czech Republic).

*As a note this is a code written in WSO2, i am unable to change it in case there are questions about that.*

Version of Java i am using for this is: openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14

**Link:** [WSO2 platform](https://wso2.com/)

Comment: On February 23 1947 the Czech Republic (Czechoslovakia, at the time) passed from the GMT timezone to the CET one, so clocks went 1 hour ahead. The opposite happened on December 1 1946 (CET->GMT, -1 hour). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_time_(clock_lag)#Czechoslovakia) as for why this happened.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. This sound legit.

Comment: Can you post it as an answer so that i can mark it as correct?

Comment: Done :) Anyway, whenever I see weird time behavior I check [Time and Date](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/czech-republic/prague?year=1947) or similar websites to see if anything weird happened at the time.

Comment: @user15244370 I wrote the note that thats how WSO2 has it implemented. Not my code

Comment: It may be outside of your control, but I recommend you don’t use `TimeZone` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `ZoneId`, or for a date use `LocalDate`. All are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: The code is very problematic. Not only as I said, the `Calendar` class is poorly designed and long outdated, also the code is flawed. Setting the zone offset (filed no. 15) to the raw offset is wrong and probably the source of the problem you are asking about. Probably the original programmers were not able to use `Calendar` correctly exactly because its design is so confusing and cumbersome.

Comment: What is `WSO2`? Please define, or link to definition.

Comment: @BasilBourque it's [this](https://wso2.com/) platform. I had the... ahem... pleasure to work with their API gateway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On February 23 1947 the [Czech Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_Republic) ([Czechoslovakia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czechoslovakia), at the time) passed from the GMT timezone to the CET one, so clocks went 1 hour ahead. The opposite happened on December 1 1946 (CET->GMT, -1 hour).

This happened because the local government at the time implemented [Winter Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_time_(clock_lag)#Czechoslovakia), for the same reason we usually have [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), that is to (supposedly) save on energy consumption.

Link: [*Time Changes in Prague Over the Years* on timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/czech-republic/prague)

Comment: Very interesting! I would add the word "supposedly" to the last sentence. The energy savings promised by DST have never been proven.

Answer (score 3):

The [Answer by Federico klez Culloca](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66776911/642706) is correct, and historically interesting.

In addition to that, I’ll point out that you are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. We can use *java.time* to see the change in offset explained in that other Answer.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

Here is a rewrite of your code to avoid those legacy classes.

First, establish the date.

```java
int year = 1947;
int month = 2;
int day = 23;
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(year,month,day);
```

Next, pick a couple of time-of-day values. 1 AM is before the 2 AM jump to 3 AM, and 4 AM is after the jump. Let's look at both.

```java
LocalTime beforeJump = LocalTime.of( 1 , 0 ) ;
LocalTime afterJump = LocalTime.of( 4 , 0 ) ;
```

Define the time zone as a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html).

```java
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Prague" ) ;
```

Combine to determine a moment, getting a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```java
ZonedDateTime zdtBeforeJump = ZonedDateTime.of( localDate , beforeJump , z );
ZonedDateTime zdtAfterJump = ZonedDateTime.of( localDate , afterJump , z );
```

When run:

```
zdtBeforeJump.toString() = 1947-02-23T01:00Z[Europe/Prague]
zdtAfterJump.toString() = 1947-02-23T04:00+01:00[Europe/Prague]
```

We can see in that generated text that the offset-from-UTC changed from zero hours-minutes-seconds as indicated by the `Z` (Zulu time) to an offset of 1 hour ahead of UTC.

We can interrogate for the offsets by code. From the `ZoneId` object, obtain the zone rules as a [`ZoneRules`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html) object. This provides a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of this particular region.

Adjust from our time zones to an offset of zero, producing the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) object required by [`ZoneRules#getOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getOffset(java.time.Instant)). Then ask the rules for the exact offset-from-UTC in effect at that moment in that zone. We get a [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) object as a result.

```java
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules();
ZoneOffset offsetBeforeJump = rules.getOffset( zdtBeforeJump.toInstant() );
ZoneOffset offsetAfterJump = rules.getOffset( zdtAfterJump.toInstant() );
```

When run.

```
offsetBeforeJump.toString() = Z
offsetAfterJump.toString() = +01:00
```

You can see all that code together [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/u7M4GY).

➥ Same results as we saw with the generated text: Zero offset before the jump, and +01:00 after the jump.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: The other answer is spot-on but does not connect the reader with Java date-time API. This answer fills that gap.